# How to disable a bootstrap tab after an event using angularJs

Tags: angularjs, tabs

I have a set of tabs like this:

```
    <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
```

I want to disable the second one, this is my function:

```
$scope.showThird = function(){
            $('a[href="#three"]').tab('show');
//here I want to disable the click on the second tab
}
```

Any help please !

Comment: what is tab ? https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ I recommend using angular-bootstrap to avoid mixing jquery selectors with angular logics

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add a callback to show the tab you should just use the built-in default actions and watch for the "hide tab event". You can then add a "disabled" class to the tab in that event.

```
   $('.nav-tabs a').on('hide.bs.tab', function(event){
        var x = $(event.target);         // the tab about to be hidden
         // if this is the tab you want to disable then add a disabled class
         if(x.text() == "Two") {
            $(event.target).addClass('disabled');
            // Still clickable though, so see docs referenced below
         }
    });
```

Check the docs for disabling a tab here
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html